# pymongo: Document must be an instance of dict

Tags: pymongo, google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Afternoon,
I'm facing a problem with **pymongo**, I'm not able to set up correctly the parameter to insert into MongoDB via insert_many(). I came across with de following error:

[image: Insert error]

> TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON,
> bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from
> collections.MutableMapping [while running 'Insere no MongoDB']

What am I doing wrong ?

```
class InsertMongoDB(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        arqJson=json.loads(element)

        client = MongoClient("mongodb://user:password@mkp-cr-marketplace-core.lcr88.gcp.mongodb.net/db-poc-base360?retryWrites=true&w=majority%20")
        db = client['db-poc-base360']
        db.tbPropostaSucesso.insert_many(arqJson)

        # tbPropostaErro = db['tbPropostaErro']
        # tbPropostaErro

        resultado = 0

        yield resultado
```

I receive a messagem from Google PubSub and forward it to a method called InsertMongoDB().
I don't know how to suit my massage, whose value is in a json format, to use it correctly in the insert_many().

When I debug my variable "arqJson" has :

[image: ![arqjson]

The json that I'm using is :

```
{
    "Status": "Sucesso ",
    "Documento": {
        "Apolice": [{
            "ItemAuto": [{
                "nmTipo": "FOX",
                "nrItem": "000001",
                "nmMarca": "VOLKSWAGEN",
                "aaModelo": "2017",
                "cdModelo": "0017664",
                "nmModelo": "TRENDLINE 1.0 FLEX 12V 5P",
                "aaFabricacao": "2016",
                "nmTipoVeiculo": "Hatch"
            }, {
                "nmTipo": "FOX",
                "nrItem": "000001",
                "nmMarca": "VOLKSWAGEN",
                "aaModelo": "2017",
                "cdModelo": "0017664",
                "nmModelo": "TRENDLINE 1.0 FLEX 12V 5P",
                "aaFabricacao": "2016",
                "nmTipoVeiculo": "Hatch"
            }],
            "ItemProp": [{
                "dsUF": "MG",
                "idLocal": "000001",
                "dsCidade": "BELO HORIZONTE",
                "dsEndereco": "RUA RUA RUA",
                "dsComplemento": "CASA"
            }],
            "cdEmpresa": "1",
            "idApolice": "501741",
            "idEndosso": "000000",
            "cdCarteira": "431",
            "cdSucursal": "010",
            "cdPatrimonio": "1",
            "nrItemContrato": "2",
            "dsTipoDocumento": "A",
            "cdVeiculoSegurado": "1"
        }],
        "Cliente": [{
            "cdCliente": "1",
            "nmCliente": "Lucas",
            "nrCpfCnpj": "4355582833",
            "icRegistroAtivo": "1",
            "cdAcaoInformacao": "A",
            "dtAcaoInformacao": "2020-02-02",
            "cdServicoAcaoInformacao": "cdServicoAcao",
            "cdUsuarioAcaoInformacao": "cdUsuarioAcao"
        }, {
            "cdCliente": "2",
            "nmCliente": "Lucas",
            "nrCpfCnpj": "43331971",
            "icRegistroAtivo": "1",
            "cdAcaoInformacao": "A",
            "dtAcaoInformacao": "2020-02-01",
            "cdServicoAcaoInformacao": "cdServicoAcao2",
            "cdUsuarioAcaoInformacao": "cdUsuarioAcao2"
        }],
        "Mensagem": [{
            "cdMensagem": "1",
            "dsMensagem": "Teste de mensagem"
        }],
        "EnderecoCobranca": [{
            "dsUF": "RS",
            "dsBairro": "INTEGRAÇÃO",
            "dsCidade": "PAROBE",
            "cdEndereco": 1,
            "dsEndereco": "RUA RUA RUA",
            "nrEndereco": "280",
            "dsComplemento": "",
            "icRegistroAtivo": "1",
            "cdAcaoInformacao": "A",
            "dtAcaoInformacao": "2020-02-02",
            "cdServicoAcaoInformacao": "cdServicoAcao",
            "cdUsuarioAcaoInformacao": "cdUsuarioAcao"
        }, {
            "dsUF": "SP",
            "dsBairro": "INTEGRAÇÃO2",
            "dsCidade": "POC2",
            "cdEndereco": 2,
            "dsEndereco": "RUA B",
            "nrEndereco": "222",
            "dsComplemento": "CASA 2",
            "icRegistroAtivo": "1",
            "cdAcaoInformacao": "A",
            "dtAcaoInformacao": "2020-02-01",
            "cdServicoAcaoInformacao": "cdServicoAcao2",
            "cdUsuarioAcaoInformacao": "cdUsuarioAcao2"
        }]
    }
}
```

**2020/11/20:**

At the moment I'm struggling with the format of arqJson that I need to use in the insert_one(arqJson).

[image: Parameter format]

I forgot to mention that my method **InsertMongoDB** receives the arqJson from another method called **InsertPostgreSQL**.

InsertPostgreSQL does:

- Receive the message from Pubsub;
- -Transform the element : json.dumps(json.loads(element))
- Save it into arqJson. After that, InsertMongoDB is called.
  At this moment, I don't know how to format "element" (whose type is list) and save it into arqJson, because I have this error:

> raise TypeError("%s must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, "
> TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON,
> bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from
> collections.MutableMapping [while running 'Insere no MongoDB']

Thank you,
Juliano

Comment: The first error is because your JSON contains a single document not multiple docs for an insert many. If you use brackets like this `db.tbPropostaSucesso.insert_many([arqJson])` and convert it to a list with a single element it will work. Or you can try `insert_one(arqJson)`.

Comment: Hi @DaveStSomeWhere
I tried and i got : 
    **raise TypeError("%s must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, "
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping [while running 'Insere no MongoDB']**
How do i convert to a dict ? thank you

Comment: I forgot to mention that my method **InsertMongoDB** receives the arqJson from another method called **InsertPostgreSQL**. 

**InsertPostgreSQL** does: 
- Receive the message from Pubsub;
-Transform the element : json.dumps(json.loads(element))      
- Save it into arqJson.
After that, **InsertMongoDB** is called. 
At this moment, I don't know how to format "element" and save it into arqJson.  =(

Comment: I ended up not converting, I let it as a list and I accessed the element like this: **arqJson=json.loads(element[0][0])**.  It worked, not sure if it is the best way but it worked well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is :

> The first error is because your JSON contains a single document not
> multiple docs for an insert many. If you use brackets like this
> db.tbPropostaSucesso.insert_many([arqJson]) and convert it to a list
> with a single element it will work. Or you can try
> insert_one(arqJson). – DaveStSomeWhere 5 hours ago

Thank you DaveStSomeWhere

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and what worked for me was adding `retryWrites=false` to the connection URL:

```
mongodb+srv://user:pass@server/etc...etc?retryWrites=false
```